# How can I manage to make a line of code run once?

Tags: java, netbeans

When my form opens, it runs a song. When I go into my option frame and come back to my main frame, it re-runs the code. Now I did a while loop and works and all but the thing is where should I declare the initial value? If I declare on `windowOpened` it always resets to 0 thus always doing my loop again.

My code in the `openedWindow` event

```
int sound = 0;          
while (sound < 1) {
    try 
    {
        InputStream test = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("musics/menu.wav");
        AudioStream Audio = new AudioStream(test);   
        AudioPlayer.player.start(Audio); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e){}

    sound = sound + 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The InputStream and AudioStream should be instance variables of some object. If they are residing in the function `openedWindow`, they will be garbage collector after the function has finished running.

Instead, you should instantiate them in the class that needs access the them, possibly in a constructor method.

Also, make the sound variable an instance variable of the class too. This way it won't get reset each time `openedWindow` is called.

Or instead use a boolean flag variable to indicate if the sound has been played:

```
class MyWindowListener implements WindowListener {
    boolean soundPlayed = false;
    ...
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        if (!soundPlayed) {
            // play the sound
            soundPlayed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, but this is not related to the issue the OP is having, so why posting this as an answer?

Comment: The sound variable should be an instance variable of the class too. I think that would fix his problem.

Comment: James, the while loop is an infinite loop, it will create new instances and re-start the music, whether you instantiate them in or outside it.

Comment: @Stultuske The while loop will only run once, so it is pointless anyway.

Comment: while(true) ... <- you think that will only run once?
Nope, just spotted my error. I was wrong,

Comment: @Stultuske `while (sound < 1) {`, maybe you need to refresh the page.

Comment: Is there simply any way to make `int sound = 0;` execute once? That's all I need.

Comment: @Jack, you need some way for the variable to live outside the function that's using it. Either you more the sound variable into an instance variable of the class, or you create a boolean flag instance variable and use that to determine whether the sound should be played.

Comment: @JamesBuck Alright if I call int sound = 0; in my main class, how do I call it back into my frame so my loops sees the sound ? I tried doing int sound2 = ProjetFinal. with the usual for calling in a static variable right? But it's not working out.

Comment: @JamesBuck I can implement a new class listener in any frame right?

Comment: @Jack it's not great to use a static variable in your main class, but you can if you want. If your main class is called ProjectFinal you'd do `ProjectFinal.sound` to access the variable from another class. And yes, you can have a window listener for each frame.

Comment: @JamesBuck Alright, it didn't work using statics variables even though it should, don't understand why, everything makes sense and no error. I guess I will need to try the boolean method, even though I don't understand much. If I have questions about it I will ask you. Thanks.